# Como insertar el ultimo registro ingresado en una tabla en otra tabla?

Tags: oracle

Me explico. Tengo una tabla que se llama OBS_SITEDS que funciona como tabla historial de todas las obervaciones que se ingresan, esta tabla tiene los siguientes campos: codigo, fecha, observacion Y tengo la otra tabla que se llama CRED_CTACTE donde necesito que el ultimo registro del campo observacion ingresado en la tabla OBS_SITEDS se muestre en esta tabla(CRED_CTACTE), esta tabla tiene los siguientes campos id_ctacte, fecha, observacion, nro_ctacte.

Las dos tablas se unen mediante el id_ctacte. En la tabla OBS_SITEDS el campo codigo es el id_ctacte de esta tabla.

Estoy usando ORACLE.

Alguien que me pueda ayudar.

Gracias.

Comment: y que intentaste? un trigger?

Comment: Puedes poner el código que has intentado? Quieres ingresar todo el registro o sólo el campo observación? Quieres que se haga de forma automática con un trigger o lo quieres hacer manual?

Comment: Intente con esta consulta: UPDATE cred_ctacte c, (SELECT observacion FROM obs_siteds WHERE codigo = '001') o SET c.observacion = o.observacion WHERE c.id_ctacte = '001' , pero me sale el error missing SET keyword, quiero ingresar solo el campo observación, lo quiero hacer manual